# Convert a hexadecimal number to decimal, octal number to decimal in PHP without using functions

Tags: php, hex, octal

So, I was asked this PHP question by one of my colleagues.

What will be the output of the following code?

```
<php
     echo 0x33, ' birds sit on ', 022, ' trees.';
?>
```

The above script evaluates to `51 birds sit on 18 trees.` I know, `0x33` represents a hexadecimal number and `022` represents a octal number.

One can answer this question by running this script. Is there anyway to convert hexadecimal numbers (base 16) and octal numbers (base 8) to decimal numbers (base 10) without using functions like hexdec() and octdec()?

---

### Answer:

As this question was closed, I was unable to post an answer to this question. You cannot simply refuse to answer if an interviewer asks the same question in an interview or convince the interviewer to use some PHP function to get the answer.

Suppose, if you want to find out 4 to the power of 2, there are functions in PHP like `pow(4, 2)`. But a developer should have an idea to evaluate these kind of basic questions.

Questions like these are worthless and aren't useful in real world, but they are worth discussing about, when it comes to interviews and exams.

Enough said. Here's the answer: (thanks to Google)

**Converting a Hexadecimal number to Decimal number:**

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|   Hexadecimal   |     Decimal      |
+------------------------------------+
|       0         |        0         |
|       1         |        1         |
|       2         |        2         |
|       3         |        3         |
|       4         |        4         |
|       5         |        5         |
|       6         |        6         |
|       7         |        7         |
|       8         |        8         |
|       9         |        9         |
|       A         |        10        |
|       B         |        11        |
|       C         |        12        |
|       D         |        13        |
|       E         |        14        |
|       F         |        15        |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

**Example 1:**

Hex number is 0x33, (ignore 0x at the beginning)

1. Get the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal number from the above table. 3 equals 3, so 33 equals 33.
2. As hex is a base 16 number, multiply every digit with 16 power of digit location. (Digit location is 0 based and starts from 0, right to the left)
3. 0x33 = (3 * 16<sup>1</sup>) + (3 * 16<sup>0</sup>)
4. 0x33 = 48 + 3
5. 0x33 = 51

**Example 2:**

Hex number is 0xA, (ignore 0x at the beginning)

1. Get the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal number from the above table. A equals 10.
2. As hex is a base 16 number, multiply every digit with 16 power of digit location.
3. 0xA = (10 * 16<sup>0</sup>)
4. 0xA = 10 * 1
5. 0xA = 10

**Converting an Octal number to Decimal number:**

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|     Octal       |     Decimal      |
+------------------------------------+
|       0         |        0         |
|       1         |        1         |
|       2         |        2         |
|       3         |        3         |
|       4         |        4         |
|       5         |        5         |
|       6         |        6         |
|       7         |        7         |
|       10        |        8         |
|       11        |        9         |
|       12        |        10        |
|       13        |        11        |
|       14        |        12        |
|       15        |        13        |
|       16        |        14        |
|       17        |        15        |
|       20        |        16        |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

**Example 1:**

Octal number is 022

1. Get the decimal equivalent of octal number from the above table. 022 equals 022.
2. As octal is a base 8 number, multiply every digit with 8 power of digit location. (Digit location is 0 based and starts from 0, right to the left)
3. 022 = (0 * 8<sup>2</sup>) + (2 * 8<sup>1</sup>) + (2 * 8<sup>0</sup>)
4. 022 = 0 + 16 + 2
5. 022 = 18

**Example 2:**

Octal number is 010

1. Get the decimal equivalent of octal number from the above table. 010 equals 010.
2. As octal is a base 8 number, multiply every digit with 8 power of digit location.
3. 010 = (0 * 8<sup>2</sup>) + (1 * 8<sup>1</sup>) + (0 * 8<sup>0</sup>)
4. 010 = 0 + 8 + 0
5. 010 = 8

In our case:

```
<php
     echo 0x33, ' birds sit on ', 022, ' trees.'; // outputs, 51 birds sit on 18 trees.
?>
```

Hope this helps other PHP developers who are looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: It gets converted to a decimal number when you print it so what is the question?

Comment: Is there anyway to mathematically calculate decimal value of a hexadecimal number and octal number like we convert decimal numbers into binary and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes?! But for what do you need it? I don't see where your problem/question is and what your goal is?

Comment: How can someone answer these kind of questions when they appear in a exam where you'll have no access to server to run the code. Is it possible to calculate their values using a pen and paper?

Comment: 1. *in a exam* If you have enough practice you can also write code on paper and debug it with reading (I wrote over thousands of code lines on paper) 2. *Is it possible to calculate their values using a pen and paper?* YES, But this wouldn't have to do much with coding to do, more with mathematics (-> Means off topic on SO)

Comment: Of course there is ways to do that. Otherwise, functions like [`hexdec` and `octdec`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/math.c#_php_math_basetozval) wouldn't work. The question is why would you need to do that when these functions exist? If you want to learn the algorithms for that, please find your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+hex+to+dec and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+octal+to+dec

Comment: This is a question more suitable for [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

For a number *n<sub>i</sub>n<sub>i-1</sub>...n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>0</sub>* (i.e. 1234 would have n<sub>3</sub>=1, n<sub>2</sub>=2, n<sub>1</sub>=3, n<sub>0</sub>=4) in base *x* you can calculate its decimal value as:

Sum <sub>j=0 to i</sub> n<sub>j</sub> ⋅ *x*<sup>j</sup>

So if 1234 would be in base 16, we would have 4 ⋅ 16<sup>0</sup> + 3 ⋅ 16<sup>1</sup> + 2 ⋅ 16<sup>2</sup> + 1 ⋅ 16<sup>3</sup> = 4660.

This is really nothing else than the working of the numeral system. Also note that a base conversion from 10 to 10 equals the identity function.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion.

Comment: I though this site is about programming not mathematics? Or where is the coding aspects here? OR for what do we have: http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Rizier123 it's kind of about explanation of the internal working of some function. But sure, close it, I would understand.